# SWV in STM32F302 - printf() with different characters

Tags: debugging, stm32, microcontroller, stm32cubeide

I found some answers that didn't solve my issue for STM32F302.
I configured the debug run as follows, to `printf()` in the SWV ITM Data Console:

[IMG-Debug_Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd3qu.png)

I implemented the `_write` function as follows:

```c
int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
{
     int DataIdx;
     for (DataIdx = 0; DataIdx < len; DataIdx++)
     {
         ITM_SendChar((*ptr++));
     }
     return len;
}
```

And tried to setup the sys clock for "Asynchronous Trace" and "Serial Wire", none worked and I keep getting the same output (SWV Graph does not work either):

[IMG-SWV_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr7Iv.png)

Any suggestion about this issue? I just want to debug the variable to make sure I'm getting the correct measurement.

*PS. Just a brief of my project: An ADC for a light sensor. I need to generate a graph from a laser sample measurement. Make this measurement with the STM32 and a photodiode, finish the  measurement and send the .csv or .txt from USB to a computer to analyse the data.*

Answer (score 2):

I found what my problem was:

My "Core Clock (MHz)", in the debug settings, was wrong and that's why my SWV was not working properly

Comment: Just to clarify - the "Core Clock" in the debugger meny has to be the same as the HCLK clock in the 'Clock Configuration' GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If no SWV data - you need to connect the SWO pin to ST-LINKV2. The SWV data transmission is on the SWO pin. On my STM32F3DISCOVERY, the SB10 was not soldered, SB10 connecting the PB3 SWO pin to the T_SWO debugger net. After soldering SB10 SWV work perfectly.